# jQuery Validation with Update Panel C#

Tags: c#, jquery, updatepanel

I am using `UpdatePanel` for `asp.net` Controls. So, to validate it I am using `jquery` `onEachRequest`. It is also working fine.
But, main issue is that It stops executing postback of `DropDownList`. Means, It does not postback to retrive data.
**My Code :**

```
function onEachRequest(sender, args) {
    if ($("#form1").valid()==false) {
          args.set_cancel(true);
    }
}
function pageLoad() {           
      $('#<%= btnPayment.ClientID %>').click(function () {
            $("#form1").validate({
                rules: {
                    <%=txtName.UniqueID %>: {
                        required: true
                    }
                }, messages: {
                    <%=txtName.UniqueID %>:{
                        required: "Please enter Name."
                }
                }
            });

        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prm.add_initializeRequest(onEachRequest);
      });
}
```

How to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used below code to solve my problem :

```
function onEachRequest1(sender, args) {
     args.set_cancel(false);
}

$('#<%= Dropdown Id.ClientID %>').change(function () {
     var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
     prm.add_initializeRequest(onEachRequest1);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Does your DropDown have the AutoPostBack-Attribute?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="someIdHere" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
```